# xdg-mime install does not update files mime-type association

Tags: linux, centos, mime-types, file-association, xdgutils

I am currently not able to install and assoziate files to a new MIME-Type under CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)). I need the installation only for the current user, not for the whole system.

I am doing the following steps:

1. Creating a File-Type-Description XML "shinythings-shiny.xml"

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
     <mime-type type="text/x-shiny">
       <comment>Shiny new file type</comment>
       <glob pattern="*.shiny"/>
     </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
2. Install

   ```
   xdg-mime install shinythings-shiny.xml
   ```
3. Update Database

   ```
   update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
   ```
4. Test

   ```
   touch test.shiny
   xdg-mime query filetype test.shiny
   ```

But after all, the test still returns "text/plain". What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the creation of an empty file via `touch`. After adding content to the file the mime-type was recognized.